# How to define a comma separated list of arguments for includegraphics

Tags: errors, optional-arguments, strings, arguments

I have a large set of pictures, and I want to apply predefined settings to each using the optional argument of the `\includegraphics` macro from the graphicx package.

I would like to define the settings once at the top of the file (like `\def\settings{width=\textwidth, angle=90}`), and then apply them to all of my images so that I can modify all of the settings from one place.

If I run the following code block, it gives me the versions of the error "**Package xkeyval Error: 'width=\textwidth, angle=90' undefined in families 'Gin'**", which seems to be because it's interpreting my entire group of settings as a single key input.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphix}
\begin{document}

    \def\settingsA{width=\textwidth, angle=90}
    \def\settingsB{page=1, scale=.1}
    \def\settingsC{angle=90, scale=.5}

    \begin{figure}
        \includegraphics[\settingsA]{filename1.png}
        \label{fig:oneofonehundred}
    \end{figure}

    \begin{figure}
        \includegraphics[\settingsB]{filename2.pdf}
        \label{fig:twoofonehundred}
    \end{figure}

    \begin{figure}
        \includegraphics[\settingsC]{filename3.jpg}
        \label{fig:threeofonehundred}
    \end{figure}

 \end{document}
```

What is the technique to modify this settings string so that it is interpreted correctly? How do I pass an optional argument that is interpreted as a set of arguments instead of one string?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `\expandafter\includegrapgics\expandafter[\settingsA]{...}` untested (currently not at pc), the key value interpreter does not expand the optional argument before parsing it

Comment: In my opinion, built-in expansion of the optional arg of `\includegraphics` is worth being filed as a feature request to  https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=graphicx

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just define new keys:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\define@key{Gin}{settingsA}[]{\setkeys{Gin}{width=\textwidth, angle=90}}
\define@key{Gin}{settingsB}[]{\setkeys{Gin}{page=1, scale=.1}}
\define@key{Gin}{settingsC}[]{\setkeys{Gin}{angle=-90, scale=.5}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\includegraphics[settingsA]{example-image-a}

\includegraphics[settingsB]{example-image-b}

\includegraphics[settingsC]{example-image-c}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A bit of explanation. The `graphicx` package relies on `keyval` provided key-value syntax and reserves `Gin` (Graphic inclusion) as the family name of the keys for `\includegraphics`. A new key is simply added by

```
\define@key{Gin}{<name>}[<default value>]{<code>}
```

The `\includegraphics[<options>]{file}` command will do

```
\setkeys{Gin}{<options>}
```

and every known key will be processed. The default empty value given for `settingsA` and so on is so that you can simply type `settingsA` without `=something`.

One could even improve it; say that in `settingsC` you want to be able to vary the angle; with

```
\define@key{Gin}{settingsC}[-90]{\setkeys{Gin}{angle=#1, scale=.5}}
```

you can specify `settingsC` for the angle to be `-90` or

```
settingsC=45
```

for the angle to be `45`.

***Caveat*** Be sure not to define an already existing key: `\define@key` would silently overwrite it.

Answer (score 2):

Make your own include graphics command.  Something like the following:

```
\newcommand\myincludegraphics[2]{%%
   \expandafter\includegraphics\expandafter[#1]{#2}}
```

The problem with your code is that in the construction

```
\includegraphics[\settingsA]{filehandle}
```

The unexpanded `\settingsA` is getting passed to the key parser where it will fail to match any keys.  By using the above command, you can write something like,

```
\myincludegraphics{\settingsA}{filehandle}
```

By using `\expandafter`, `\settingsA` will be expanded by the time `\includegraphics` has a chance to pass the optional arguments to its parser.